# Run Laravel queue on production

Tags: php, laravel-5, queue, devops, production

Could you please share your best solution for run [Laravel queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues) on production server?

For now I see next solution:

1. First start queue:

```bash
php artisan queue:work >> /var/log/queue.log &
```

2. Add to crontab:

```bash
10 2 * * * php artisan queue:restart
11 2 * * * php artisan queue:work >> /var/log/queue.log &
```

3. In case of project update on server:

```bash
php artisan down
php artisan queue:restart
#do update
php artisan queue:work >> /var/log/queue.log &
php artisan up
```

But I'm worrying about high load case. What if some job will be stucked?
Maybe you have better solution?

Comment: Could you clarify the following: Are you running on docker? Or is it on a standalone server?

Answer (score -1):

You can set up the laravel supervisor to run the queues automatically instead of using the cronjobs

Please find below the article for more details to run the queue automatically on the server without cronjob

[Integration of Laravel Supervisor to process Queues](https://laravelfacts.blogspot.com/2021/08/supervisor-integration-in-laravel.html)

Comment: In the case of high load you can break your jobs in chunks and create separate job for each chunk and also can increase timeout.